# NSFetchRequest canot fetch entity present in context

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a problem where I am inserting entities A in a context. Right after I insert all of the entities A I execute a fetch request on the context:

```
NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"A" inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError* fetchError;
NSArray* results = [ctx executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];
```

This code above is able to get all of them and I can see them in the NSLog...

Right after on the same context I try to fetch all entities A that have age = 5, like this:
(I assign "age" to the attirbute and a NSString @"5" to the value)

```
NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"A" inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@",attr,value];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:filter];
NSError* fetchError;
NSArray* results = [ctx executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];
```

THE PROBLEM IS that even though the NSLog shows an entity A with age  5 this last fetch request returns always null! Nothing.

Any suggestions? Why fetching all of them shows entities with age 5 and filtering for age 5 only does not work right after on the same context?

Thanks

Comment: What type is age in the model?

Comment: NSNumber (Integer 64) , also, I just found out that if I hard code the predicate to be @"age == 5" then it works. I'm confused now.

Comment: %@ with a string argument inserts quotation marks for a string comparison.  If the data is not a string, it will not compare... which is why I asked the type...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting age to an instance of NSNumber initalized to 5 rather than the NSString @"5".

Comment: Worked. darn, so, I thought that I could always provide a string in an NSPredicate... I guess because age is an NSNumber then it makes sense that your suggestion works, but, COULD YOU maybe give me a hint why I can't just pass in an NSString in this case? What am I missing here? Thanks!!

Comment: When you pass a string as the argument to a predicate, it automatically converts it to a "string" with quotes, which does not compare to a value of 5.